# Is there any way to hide my app's process and on installed list?

Tags: android

On Android platform, I wanna make myapp hidden on process killer and I wanna hide myapp on installed app list also.

Is it possible?

Comment: why on earth would you like to do that? To me that sounds like something only a malicious app would do.

Comment: Actually, it's a good question. I would like to hide my android anti theft app (androidlost) from the processes list so that the nice thief can't see that this app is on my phone and running. My phone is rooted and he could force-stop or even uninstall it with titanium backup or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, and I certainly hope not. Not without rooting the device and thus circumventing all security measures.

Answer (score 0):

Might be possible on a rooted device, otherwise just tell your users to stop using taskmanagers